# Issue with location of folders in Outlook 2016

Tags: email, imap, microsoft-outlook-2016

I am using Outlook 2016 and have my account setup with IMAP.

I have two external PST files on my HDD for two jobs. As emails come in and I sent emails I move them into the external PST From / To folders. Eventually I close those PST files and archive them.

[image]

My issue is that the Junk Email is now showing in the wrong place and I con't seem to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it happened. But I created a new PST file. Moved the To / From folders into it and removed the previous PST file. Now the main mailbox has a Junk Email folder.

Comment: According to your description, it seems to be the influence of the original PST file. Considering that deleting the original PST after creating a new PST file solves the problem,  would you mind marking your reply as an answe? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum. Warm thanks.

Comment: @Christy I can’t accept my answer until tomorrow.

Comment: Hi @Andrew Truckle , thanks for your reply! Please remember to mark when you have time. Have a nice day~